# Aliases for programs in /sbin/

Tags: linux, shell, alias

I have a weird problem, unfortuantely I don't know what I did to cause this, since I tried out lots of stuff on my Linux (Archlinux, 2.6.38 kernel).
The problem is: My shell is not finding programs in /sbin anymore. It looks like this:

```
[chris@myhost ~] insmod
bash: insmod: command not found
[chris@myhost ~] ls -l /sbin/insmod
-rwxr-x-r-x root root 7888 Mar 23 10:14 /sbin/insmod
[chris@myhost ~] /sbin/insmod
-- Works
```

So as you can see, the program (the problem occurs for every executable in sbin) is still there, I can start it using /sbin/name, only the short name alias seems to be corrupted. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not about aliases.  It's controlled by the `PATH` environment variable.

On many systems, root has `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` in `PATH`, but normal users don't.

If you want to type `insmod` etc without typing the full path, you can put

```
PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

in your shell settings file (e.g. `.bashrc` in your home directory).

Or you could look at `/etc/profile`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/login.defs` and see how it's setting `PATH` and change it there.

A quick way to find which file(s) to look in is running `grep -R PATH /etc` (or `grep -HIRn PATH /etc`).

Comment: That was easy, ty :)