# How to install `service` command in a Stable Debian?

Tags: debian, services

In ubuntu we do simple:

```
service MyService restart
service MyService stop
...
```

So, the `service` command is good and simple. I need this simplicity: how to install `service` command on Debian?

PS: [this is an analog question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106656), but here I need a command, not an explanation.

Comment: in debian10, `service` is not available if you login with `su`, but if you login with `su -`  or `sudo su` it will be available.. something about $PATH environment variable not being set correctly if only logging in with `su`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `service` command is part of the [sysvinit-utils](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/sysvinit-utils) package.

Install it with:

```
apt-get install sysvinit-utils
```

But most probably, it is already installed in `/usr/sbin/service`.

If it's missing in your `$PATH`, add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
```

Comment: Yes, `/usr/sbin/service`  at Debian Stable (!), thanks... Well, how to get all *sbin* aliases?  [is it?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10727/130402)

Comment: @PeterKrauss Yes, add them to you `$PATH` variable

Comment: @chaos important step : after updating .bashrc you need to logout and login back to terminal or just reload bashr   using command  `source ~/.bashrc`